# Overwrite margin style from "form-control" class on element

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have this Html.ListBox which utilizes the form-control class, which is providing it an unwanted right margin that I can't get rid of.

I don't want to overwrite the style for the class overall as I want to keep it on all other elements, but if I remove the - { @class = "form-control" } - tag on the ListBox to supply my own, it ruins it as shown in the second image, the box disappears.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
            <label class="control-label">Native Countries</label>
            @Html.ListBox("selectedCountries", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.selOpts, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

I noticed thank you's are discouraged in comments to save space for information, so thank you in advance for any answers.

[With form-control tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiihp.png)

[without tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4yPe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something to do with parent style. `form-control` did not create margin.

The worst case you could just apply the style for this specific control.

```
@Html.ListBox("selectedCountries", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.selOpts, 
       new { @class = "form-control", style = "margin-right: 0 !important" })
```

Comment: Hi Win,

Interestingly, specifying the margin-right after the form control class didn't overwrite it, but I was able to instead use "display: inline" and there is no more unwanted margin on the box. Thanks!